# How to change if/else to hash function? perl

Tags: perl

```
sub funcA{
    my ($A) = @_;  <--require 1
}
sub funcB{
    my ($A, $B) = @_;  <--require 2
}
sub funcC{
    my ($A, $B, $C) = @_;  <--require 3
}

sub funcRun{
    my ($param) = @_;
    my $other1, $other2, $other3;  <--will be assigned at ',,,,,'

    ,,,,,

    if($param eq 'a'){
        funcA, $other1;
        return;
    }elsif($param eq = 'b'){
        funcB, $other1, $other2;
        return;
    }elsif($param eq = 'c'){
        funcC, $other1, $other2, $other3;
        return;
    }
}
```

I want to change this to next code

```
sub funcA{
    my ($A) = @_;  #<--require 1
}
sub funcB{
    my ($A, $B) = @_;  #<--require 2
}
sub funcC{
    my ($A, $B, $C) = @_;  #<--require 3
}

my $hash_ref = {
    'a' => \&funcA,
    'b' => \&funcB,
    'c' => \&funcC
}

sub funcRun{
    my ($param) = @_;
    my $other1, $other2, $other3;  #<--will be assigned at ',,,,,'

    ,,,,,

    $hash_ref->{$param}(ARGUMENTS);   #<--my problem

}
```

But I can't think how to make **ARGUMENTS** section including variable number of arguments.
I considered each function to be defined in the **funcRun** code, but then I don't know the difference with if/else code. And I heard that passing 3 arguments values and accepting parameters in order from first, is not good from someone

Comment: There's usua;;y no harm in passing extra args, in which case `$hash_ref->{$param}->($other1, $other2, $other3);` would work fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Updated following a clarification.  The very last code segment may be exactly what is asked for.*

---

The design where a parameter decides what argument set to use from a list generated at runtime is what is giving you trouble; it's complicated. Not knowing about the actual problem I don't know what else to offer though (other than guesses). Perhaps clarify the use of this?

Having said that, one way to complete what you want is to store a specification of what  arguments go with a function along with the function name in the hashref; another would be to have a separate structure with argument sets for each parameter.

For example

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $dispatch = { 
    'a' => { name => \&funcA, lastidx => 0 },
    'b' => { name => \&funcB, lastidx => 1 },
    'c' => { name => \&funcC, lastidx => 2 } 
};

sub funcRun {
    my ($param) = @_; 
    my @args = qw(one two three);

    my $func    = $dispatch->{$param}{name};
    my $lastidx = $dispatch->{$param}{lastidx};

    $func->( @args[0..$lastidx] );
}    
sub funcA { say "@_" }
sub funcB { say "@_" }
sub funcC { say "@_" }

funcRun($_)  for qw(a b c);
```

Prints

```
one
one two
one two three
```

If you really need to pick arguments positionally from a list then use an array.

However, I suggest that you clarify what this is for so that we can offer a simpler design.

---

Following an explanation in a comment, a property I thought was accidental may in fact help.

If the function `funcA` indeed takes only the first argument, `funcB` the first two and `funcC` all three (from a list built at runtime), then you can nicely pass all to all of them

```
$func->( @args );

sub funcA {
    my ($A) = @_;  # arguments other than the first are discarded
    ...
}
```

Each function takes what it needs and the rest of the arguments are discarded.

Further, if functions in any way know which of a given list of arguments to take then again you can simply pass all of them.  Then they can pick their arguments either positionally

```
sub funcB {
    my ($A, undef, $B) = @_;  # if it needs first and third
    ...
}
```

or by a named key

```
# Work out what arguments are for which function
my $args = { for_A => ..., for_B => ..., for_C => ... };
...
$func->( $args );

sub funcA {
    my ($args) = @_
    my $A = $args->{for_A};
    ...
}
```

where now arguments need be stored in a hash.

Finally and best, this can all be worked out ahead of the call

```
my $dispatch = { a => \&funcA, b => \&funcB, c => \&funcC };

sub funcRun {
    my ($param) = @_;
    # Work out arguments for functions
    my $args = { a => ..., b => ..., c => ... };      

    $dispatch->{$param}->( $args->{$param} );
}
# subs funcA, funcB, funcC are the same   

funcRun($_)  for qw(a b c);
```

what requires minimal changes to your code (just store arguments in a hash).

Here neither the functions nor the dispatch table need knowledge of the possible argument lists, what is all resolved in `funcRun`.  This avoids entangling functions with outside code.

Comment: funcRun is to read a file, including while statement. For each line, I have to check whether it is matched with some regexes and if mathched, run actions(hash values). the 'other1,2,3' variables, sometimes it can be a 'group words of matched', sometimes 'line of file', sometimes 'number of line'

Comment: @nokdoo  I added a few other possible ways.  The last one may be what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem stems from the fact that you're passing in a selection of values from arbitrary, unrelated variables. The solution, therefore, is to put all the data you might want to pass to you subroutines in a single data structure and define a mechanism for extracting the correct data for each call. You already have a solution which uses an array for this, but I think it's slightly easier to understand in a hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

sub funcA{
    my ($A) = @_;
    say $A;
}
sub funcB{
    my ($A, $B) = @_;
    say "$A / $B";
}
sub funcC{
    my ($A, $B, $C) = @_;
    say "$A / $B / $C";
}

my $hash_ref = {
    'a' => { func => \&funcA, args => [ qw[ other1 ] ] },
    'b' => { func => \&funcB, args => [ qw[ other1 other2 ] ] },
    'c' => { func => \&funcC, args => [ qw[ other1 other2 other3 ] ] },
};

sub funcRun{
    my ($param) = @_;

    my %args = (
        other1 => 'foo',
        other2 => 'bar',
        other3 => 'baz',
    );

    # $hash_ref->{$param}{args} is an array reference containing
    # the names of the arguments you need.
    # @{ ... } turns that array reference into an array.
    # @args{ ... } uses that array to look up those keys in the
    # %args hash (this is called a hash slice)

    $hash_ref->{$param}{func}(@args{ @{ $hash_ref->{$param}{args} } });

}

funcRun($_) for qw[a b c];
```

But, to be honest, having stored your data in a hash, it's only a small step to passing the whole hash into every subroutine and letting them determine which data they want to use. Or even turning your hash into an object.